# Is there an English Office Language Interface Pack?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007, language, language-pack

Located in France, I have only access to a French version of Excel and would like to change it to English for programming purposes. I want to use [this model](http://labs.russell.wisc.edu/buongiorno/welcome/gfpm/), based partly on Excel VBA code. Currently it returns an error because sheets are not called "sheet" but "Feuil" in my version of Excel. There are other language related bugs which would be too long to fix (I did this 2 years ago and have to redo it now because the software was updated in between). The simplest  fix would be to change the language of Excel to English.

From the list of [Office language interface packs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-language-interface-pack-LIP-downloads-d63007c2-e8ae-41fd-8bfb-fce2857010e1). I have successfully installed the Gaelic version, changed the Office interface settings and get Excel sheets called "Bileog". But there is no English language interface pack in the list! This blog post is related: [Is there an English Office Language Interface Pack?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_language_interface_pack/2011/06/29/is-there-an-english-office-language-interface-pack/) But it mentions an English Language Pack and I couldn't find any. Since the blog post was from 2011 there might be an update on this issue.

Where can I find an English language pack for office 2007?

Comment: You do understand Office 2007 is no longer supported by Microsoft.  I think the last time I looked Microsoft only distrubutes the language packs on the version of Office it supports. An English language pack for Office 2007 would need to be purchased.  Microsoft currently does not sell the language packs for Office 2007.  *The article you linked to only apples to Office 2010 not Office 2007.*  They have not sold the language packs since July 201 so for about 5 years.

Comment: What you have downloaded is just the interface packs, those were always free, English required a language pack which had to be purchased.

Comment: @Ramhound why is there no English [interface pack](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-language-interface-pack-LIP-downloads-d63007c2-e8ae-41fd-8bfb-fce2857010e1)? Where can I purchase the English language pack?

Comment: True, there is no way to purchase the language pack you need because the support has been discontinued for your version of Office (2007).  However, you could simply find and download another version of Office (or a similar program like LibreOffice or OpenOffice) and make sure you get the English version.

Comment: @PaulRougieux - There is no English interface pack because Microsoft didn't create one.  You cannot purchase the English languag pack from Microsoft, as I pointed out, they stopped selling language packs for Office 2007 back in 2011.

Comment: @Matthew - In order to use Office 2013 or Office 2016 the author would need to purchase a license for it.  I should point out that Office 2016 language packs do not cost money.

Comment: @Matthew I want to run a model written partly in Excel VBA code, programmed with "sheet" hard coded (among other things). Similar programs (Libre office) will not work. I think I will have to purchase another version of Excel in English.

Comment: @PaulRougieux Hmmm...  Yes that would seem to be your only option...  A quick search of google reveals a number of apparently free ways to get Office 2016 and, although I could not recommend one over another, I often find that Youtube has many instructions on how to do this.  https://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft+office+2016+free+download

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between an Office `language interface pack` and an Office `language pack`.  **Office language packs that supported versions before and including Office 2013 are not free.**  Office *interface language packs* for office 2003 to Office 2013 were **free**.  Microsoft stop selling Office 2003 and Office 2007 language packs in July 2011

> Language interface packs (LIPs) change the language for the ribbon and
>   commands for some Office applications, and include a spell checker for
>   their language. LIPs are available only for the languages listed in
>   the Links to free LIP downloads section.

[Office language interface pack (LIP) downloads](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-language-interface-pack-LIP-downloads-d63007c2-e8ae-41fd-8bfb-fce2857010e1)

Microsoft's official stance on this subject is the following:

> If you have Office 2010 or an earlier version, language packs are
>   discontinued and are no longer available.

You might be able to find a third-party that will sell the English language pack.  I was able to find somebody that sold the following Office 2007 Multi-Language Pack on Amazon

[Microsoft Office Multi-Language Pack 2007](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000LC5106)

Language Packs for the current supported versions of Office do not support Office 2007.  Here is an official statement with regard to that.

> Microsoft no longer offers Office 2003 or 2007 Language packs for
>   retail purchase as of July 2011.  Please note Office 2010 language
>   packs will not work with other versions of Office (XP,2003, 2007 etc.)

[Office 2003/2007 Language Packs are no longer available!](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_language_interface_pack/2011/10/10/office-20032007-language-packs-are-no-longer-available/)

### Notice:

*I should point out that Microsoft no longer sells Office 2010 language packs either.  The information I quoted is reference to Office 2003 and Office 2007.*  This means the only language packs sold by Microsoft are for Office 2013.

Office 2016 language packs are actually free.

[Language Accessory Pack for Office 2016](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Language-Accessory-Pack-for-Office-2016-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f) and [Office 2016 - English Language Pack](https://c2rsetup.officeapps.live.com/c2r/download.aspx?ProductreleaseID=languagepack&language=en-us&platform=x86&source=O16LAP&version=O16GA)

The following chart applies to Office 2007 but it explains which languages are *language interface packs* and which languages are *languages packs*.  I have no reason to believe the information changed between Office 2007 and Office 2010.

[image]

[What is the difference between an Office 2010 Language Interface Pack (LIP) and an Office 2010 Language Pack?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_language_interface_pack/2008/10/16/what-is-the-difference-between-an-office-2010-language-interface-pack-lip-and-an-office-2010-language-pack/)

> Where can I find an English language pack for office 2007?

You would have to find a third-party who sells the language pack for Office 2007.  *Whom you purchase the language pack from is entirely up to you.*